# .exe has stopped working error when program run(c program)

Tags: c

as you can see bellow in this program. when i compile this program compile fine. when i run this program program rise .exe has stopped working. if i comment insert() function calling line then program compile as well as run fine.

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct ArrayADT {
  int capacity;
  int lastIndex;
  int * ptr;
};

struct ArrayADT * createArray(int cap) {
  struct ArrayADT * arr;
  arr = malloc(sizeof(struct ArrayADT));
  arr -> ptr = malloc(cap * sizeof(int));
  arr -> lastIndex = -1;
  arr -> capacity = cap;
  return arr;
}

void append(struct ArrayADT * arr, int data) {
  if (arr -> lastIndex == arr -> capacity - 1) {
    growArray(arr, arr -> capacity * 2, data);
    append(arr, data);
  } else {
    arr -> lastIndex += 1;
    arr -> ptr[arr -> lastIndex] = data;
  }
}

void growArray(struct ArrayADT * arr, int cap) {
  arr -> ptr = realloc(arr -> ptr, cap * sizeof(int));
  arr -> capacity = cap;
}

void insert(struct ArrayADT * arr, int index, int data) {
  int i;
  if (arr -> lastIndex < 0 || index > arr -> lastIndex + 1) {
    printf("\n Invalid Index.......");
  } else if (arr -> lastIndex == arr -> capacity - 1) {
    growArray(arr, arr -> capacity * 2);
    insert(arr, index, data);
  } else {
    for (i = arr -> lastIndex; arr -> lastIndex >= index; i--) {
      arr -> ptr[i + 1] = arr -> ptr[i];
    }

    arr -> lastIndex += 1;
    arr -> ptr[index] = data;
  }
}

void removeItem(struct ArrayADT * arr, int index) {
  if (index < 0 || index > arr -> lastIndex) {
    printf("\n invalid index... please give valid index for remove");
  } else {
    for (int i = index; i < arr -> lastIndex; i++) {
      arr -> ptr[i] = arr -> ptr[i + 1];
    }
    arr -> lastIndex -= 1;
  }
}
void display(struct ArrayADT * arr) {

  for (int i = 0; i <= arr -> lastIndex; i++) {
    printf("%d, ", arr -> ptr[i]);
  }
}

void freeMemory(struct ArrayADT * arr) {
  free(arr -> ptr);
  free(arr);
}

int main() {
  struct ArrayADT * arr;
  arr = createArray(3);
  append(arr, 10);
  append(arr, 15);
  append(arr, 8);
  append(arr, 20);
  append(arr, 25);

  insert(arr, 2, 12); // when I comment this line then progrom runs fine

  display(arr);
  printf("\n total capacity = %d", arr -> capacity);

  freeMemory(arr);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `void growArray(struct ArrayADT *arr, int cap);` and `growArray(arr, arr->capacity * 2, data);` - do you see the problem ?

Comment: always read the warnings!!!! to discipline yourself add `-Werror` to your compiler options

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is an error:

"Too many arguments to the function growArray(...) call, expected 2, have 3"

The error was in the for loop that you wrote in insert(...).
I'm going to attach here the code:

```js
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct ArrayADT {

          int capacity;
          int lastIndex;
          int *ptr;
};

struct ArrayADT * createArray(int cap) {

          struct ArrayADT *arr;
          arr = malloc(sizeof(struct ArrayADT));
          arr-> ptr = malloc(cap * sizeof(int));
          arr->lastIndex = -1;
          arr->capacity = cap;
          return arr;
}

void growArray(struct ArrayADT *arr, int cap) {

         arr->ptr = realloc(arr->ptr, cap * sizeof(int));
         arr->capacity = cap;
}

void append(struct ArrayADT *arr ,int data) {

          if(arr->lastIndex == arr->capacity - 1) {
                    growArray(arr, arr->capacity * 2);
                    append(arr, data);
          }
          else {
                    arr->lastIndex += 1;
                    arr->ptr[arr->lastIndex] = data;
          }
}

void insert(struct ArrayADT *arr, int index, int data) {

          int i;
          if(arr->lastIndex < 0 || index > arr->lastIndex + 1)
                    printf("\n Invalid Index.......");
          else if(arr->lastIndex == arr->capacity-1) {
                   growArray(arr, arr->capacity * 2);
                   insert(arr, index, data);

          }
          else {
                    for(i = arr->lastIndex; arr->lastIndex < index - 1; i--)
                              arr->ptr[i + 1] = arr->ptr[i];

                    arr->lastIndex += 1;
                    arr->ptr[index] = data;
          }
}
void removeItem(struct ArrayADT *arr, int index) {

          if(index < 0 || index > arr->lastIndex)
                    printf("\n invalid index... please give valid index for remove");
          else {
                 for(int i = index; i < arr->lastIndex ; i++)
                    arr->ptr[i] = arr->ptr[i+1];

                 arr->lastIndex -= 1;
          }
}
void display(struct ArrayADT *arr) {

          for(int i = 0; i <= arr->lastIndex; i++)
                    printf("%d, ", arr->ptr[i]);
}

void freeMemory(struct ArrayADT *arr) {

          free(arr->ptr);
          free(arr);
}
int main() {

          struct ArrayADT *arr;
          arr = createArray(3);
          append(arr, 10);
          append(arr, 15);
          append(arr, 8);
          append(arr, 20);
          append(arr, 25);

          insert(arr, 5, 12);

          display(arr);
          printf("\n total capacity = %d", arr->capacity);

          freeMemory(arr);
          return 0;
}
```

Note that I leave it as much similar as I can to your code to be more clear.
The problem inside the for loop was that:

- you should increase "i" instead of decreasing it
- exit condition to < and not to <=

Furthermore as [0___________](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6110094/0) suggests, always read the warnings, please!

Cheers,
Denny